# onDataChange() method not getting called. Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase, and having problem with onDataChange() method.
onDataChange()  is not getting called.

Here is my Code:

```
DatabaseReference mref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("songs");
        System.out.println("I am in Oncreate()");

        ValueEventListener event = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                System.out.println("I am in onDataChange()");

                for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String name  =ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    System.out.println("I am printing name: "+name);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            System.out.println("Firebase Error"+ error.toException());

            }
        };
    
        mref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(event);
    System.out.println("I called mref.addlistner...()");
```

Firebase access rules are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Here is my Database Structure:
[image]

Comment: Is `System.out.println("Firebase Error"+ error.toException());`,  showing something in the logcat? Is your onDataChange or onCancelled even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo No, Nothing in the logcat.   onDataChange or onCancelled was not even triggered. That's what I am saying. Not even   `System.out.println("I am in onDataChange()"); `  or   `System.out.println("Firebase Error"+ error.toException());`  was ever executed.

Comment: Most likely you cannot connect to Firebase servers, or, you don't have an internet connection on the user's device.

Comment: @AlexMamo Problem Solved. I was not specifying database url in `getInstance()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In onDataChanged() method you should add an if condition like this, then paste your code inside.

```
if(snapshot.exists()){}
```

This will make sure that your snapshot really is there.

Comment: But not even  `System.out.println("I am in onDataChange()");` this statement is printed.